# Best way to get blog post titles along with blog name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have 2 tables:

> ```
> Blog      BlogPosts
> BlogId    BlogPostId
> Name      BlogId
>           Title
> ```

When I am retrieving records, I want BlogPosts in CSV format. I've created a user defined function for this and pass in BlogId as a parameter. Is there any better way than this? Making DB requests in user defined functions can often be performance killer. Do you suggest any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select B.Name,
       (
         select ', '+BP.Title
         from BlogPosts as BP
         where B.BlogId = BP.BlogId
         for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring((./text())[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as BlogPosts
from Blog as B
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c2b4/1/0)